# Clearing view from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I have a viewController, in which I have a view in which I draw like in Paint by tapping. In that controller I have a method to clear screen -

```
- (void) clearS
{
    [(TouchTrackerView *)self.view clear];
}
```

Now, as I don't want to occupy my screen with buttons, I have button in another screen that resets application to starting position, and I want it to clear screen. That button belongs to different view controller, and among other things I want it to call my drawing view controller and ask it to wipe screen clear. So I have setup notifications, like this in draw view contoller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(clearS) name:@"clearScreen" object: nil];
```

And like this in my view controller from where I click a button:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"clearScreen" object: nil];
```

As I understand, when the button gets clicked, notification gets posted, and method is called. And it crashes.

```
[(TouchTrackerView *)self.view clear]
```

As I understand the problem is that at the moment of method invocation the "self" variable is my non-drawing view controller, and it tries to perform clear method on view of itself, which it lacks and crashes.

How do I send the method to correct view controller?
Is there a flaw in my thinking? Maybe this can be approached in a better way?

**EDIT:**
I have found the problem,

```
[(TouchTrackerView *)self.view clear]
```

calls view and it is UIScrollView, and it does not support clear method. So I have made a property containing the correct view, and changed it to

```
[(TouchTrackerView *)self.correctView clear]
```

and it works like a charm.

I have chosen notification because it is only two lines of code, and I am beginner and it is hard for me to wrap my head around delegates, so I will leave this as it is, especially that it works.

Comment: Generally it is inadvisable to use casts (the "`(TouchTrackerView *)`") like you have in your example. In well written code, casts are rarely needed. And, as demonstrated in this case, when you use a cast, you run a risk of letting the compiler think that an object is of a particular type, which it might not actually be in reality. Try to avoid casts if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the philosophical level, while I'm sympathetic to the observations from others that you could replace the notification with a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) pattern (or, better, delegate [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH45-SW1) pattern), it strikes me that this is not an appropriate example of having two controllers communicating directly to each other at all. You probably should be employing a [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) model, where the editing view controller, `A`, is designed for the editing of a drawing (and thus updates the model and coordinates the view) and the reset view controller, `B`, should just update/reset the model. If `A` needs to be informed of model changes, then apply a delegate-protocol pattern there, between the model and controller `A`. But I don't think `B` should be communicating with `A` at all.

At a practical level, there's absolutely no reason why notifications shouldn't work just fine. Unfortunately, you haven't shared enough for us to answer the question. You should share the specifics of the error message and we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

I think that notifications, which are in nature a one-to-many method of communication are not good to use here. A better approach would be to hook one as the delegate of the other -> once the button is pressed and the corresponding IBAction is invoked, the delegate (in your case, the view controller you use for drawing) should get a message and perform whatever it is it needs to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid notifications unless you are trying to broadcast out some info that multiple objects may be interested in.

A better approach might be to create a delegate protocol for the painting view controller --

So the PaintingViewControllerDelegate Protocol may have methods like so

- (void) paintingViewControllerWillClear:(PaintingViewController*)paintingViewController;
- (void) paintingViewControllerDidClear:(PaintingViewController*)paintingViewController;

Now the controller with the buttons becomes the delegate to the PaintingViewController and that object provides the methods of the PaintingViewControllerDelegate protocol as needed.